# postgresql: упрощение sql запроса в хранимке

Tags: sql, postgresql, параметры, хранимые-процедуры

есть у меня такая хранимая функция:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_stats(
    tbl text,
    field text,
    expr_where text DEFAULT ''::text)
    RETURNS TABLE(count bigint, value integer) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$

DECLARE
    
    sql2 TEXT := '
    WITH selected_t AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            ' || tbl || ' ' || expr_where || '
    )
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS count, ' || field || '::integer AS value
    FROM
        selected_t
    GROUP BY ' || field;
    
    sql TEXT := '
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS count, ' || field || '::integer AS value
    FROM
        ' || $1 || '
    GROUP BY ' || field;
    
BEGIN   

    IF expr_where = '' THEN
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql
        USING tbl;
    ELSE
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql2
        USING 'selected_t';
    END IF;
    
END;
```

указав название таблицы, поле и условие можно получить статистику по кол-ву сущностей в указанном поле, всё работает, всё ок

хотелось бы его сделать более компактным, при этом сохранить читаемость (ну и производительность, т.е. чего-то лишнего не добавлять), сделал такой запрос:

```
DECLARE
    
    selected_t TEXT := '
    WITH selected_t AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            ' || tbl || ' ' || expr_where || '
    )';
    
    sql TEXT := '
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS count, ' || field || '::integer AS value
    FROM
        ' || $1 || '
    GROUP BY ' || field;
    
BEGIN   

    IF expr_where = '' THEN
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql
        USING tbl;
    ELSE
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE selected_t || sql
        USING 'selected_t';
    END IF;
    
END;
```

и вот он как раз работает некорректно - есть ли условие в параметрах функции или нет код выполняется всегда так как будто никакого условия нет

подскажите почему так произошло и как можно исправить, может запрос вообще по другому стоит написать?

Comment: Ну добавьте отладочку-то - выведите куда-нить полученное значение параметра, результат его сравнения с пустой строкой, пометку, какая ветка выполнена, и текст собранного в этой ветке запроса. Может, параметр надо тупо тримануть... или сравнивать с литералом, явно преобразованным в TEXT.

Comment: @Akina, кстати хороший вопрос - а как вывести текст запроса, пусть скажем функция его не выполняет, а просто выводит текст

Comment: сделал выдачу именно текста запроса - оказалось, что $1 берется как 1 параметр в функции, а не 1 параметр в USING

Comment: *как вывести текст запроса* Я обычно создаю дебаг-таблицу да вставляю в неё записи - штамп времени, идентификатор точки в коде, откуда выполняется вставка, и все нужные мне данные, собранные в одну вменяемую строку. Типа `INSERT INTO debug VALUES (NOW(), 'Точка 5', 'param1="' || param1 || '", ' || 'length of param2=' || LENGTH(param2) || ', ' || 'test result=' || (param3 = 'literal') || '.');`

Comment: Да! таблица для дебага должна быть **НЕ** транзакционной. Иначе при ошибке всё нафиг откатится, и записанная дебаг-информация удалится.